# Scale web app for mobile

Tags: jquery, html, iphone, web-applications

I've got a game developed using JQuery, HTML, and CSS, made to run in a web browser.

Now, I need to get it running in a mobile (specifically iPhone) browser, with a little optimization so its nice and pretty.

Is there a way to scale the entire app? Ideally, it would launch in landscape by default in mobile safari, though the dimensions of the canvas and the background image are 800x600, which obviously will not fit in an iPhone browser in landscape.

So, my questions is, is there a way to scale an entire web app like this? Essentially take the entire thing (images, canvas, etc) and make them smaller by a certain factor?

Thanks!

Comment: for future reference, from experience I advise to design for mobile and work up on your future apps. Saves a hell of a lot of pain.

Answer (score 0):

Websites can be resized for mobiles by using the  tag below:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```